# How to tell if child Node.js Process was from fork() or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, fork

I have a small application that could be executed by a fork or directly by a developer, and I would for it to get configured slightly differently depending on how it was started.

I know that I could always pass in arguments to to signal that it was a fork, but I was just curious if there was a way to tell if I could somehow know in the child process if it came from a `fork()`. I looked around in `process` but didn't find anything telling.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can check if [`process.send`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle) exists in your application. When it was started using `fork()` it will exist.

```
if (process.send === undefined) { 
  console.log('started directly');
} else {
  console.log('started from fork()');
}
```

Personally, I would probably set an environment variable in the parent and check for that in the child:

```
// parent.js
child_process.fork('./child', { env : { FORK : 1 } });

// child.js
if (process.env.FORK) {
  console.log('started from fork()');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The environment variable looks like a good way to get it done.

Comment: Two great ideas in one answer, wish I could upvote twice!